# Same code running slower in parallel than serial on HPC cluster

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, slurm, hpc

I need to fit some thousand models and bootstrap them.
To do this I have a list of model formulas that I pass to some costume functions that do the fitting and bootstrapping, and extract the parameters and model performance.

Since it will take quite a while, I need/want to use parallel computing and I am doing this on a HPC cluster (fyi: Graham from Compute Canada which use SLURM).

Although I am quite new to both parallel comupting and HPC clusters, I managed to run succesfully my code on the HPC cluster.
However I see that my serial version of the code runs way faster than when I run it in parallel and I do not understand why.

I know that there is some overhead involved in setting up the environments for parallel processing, but from my understanding this is a cost that happens only once at the beginnig.

In my code I actually time the running of the model fitting functions and it it this that is actually taking a lot of time to run in the parallel version of the code.

Can anyone help me understand why is this happening and how I can solve the problem?

In my mind, once the overhead price is payed then the code should take the same time on 1 core as on 5 or more cores.

Below is my code:

##### script common to both parallel and serial version of the code:

```
library(FFspatial) # my package with the function I customize; 
library(parallel)


# =============================
# load data 
# =============================

# load the model formula set
load('./R_output/R_objects/urchin_intensity-model_set_buffers.Rdata')
# load the dataset to be used to fit models
df<-read.csv('./R_output/datasets/urchin_intensity-data_prep-dataframe_hype_soft_buffers.csv')

# =============================
# Processing
# =============================

# spilt the model set in chunks of 40 model formulas each (to allow the parallel processing: i.e. each chung will be sent to a core)
length(fmla_set)/40

div<-as.factor(rep(1:197,each=40 ))
div<-div[1:length(fmla_set)]
fmla_set_split<-split(fmla_set,div)

# clean unused opbject to free memory
rm( 'div', 'fmla_set')
gc()

# reduce the model list for testing so that eah chunk contain 2 formulas instead of 40
TEMP_2<-lapply(fmla_set_split, function(x) x[1:2])
```

##### Serial version:

```
res<-lapply(10:15 , function(xx)  { # only runs chuncks 10 to 15 
            
        # Run FIXED models and time the execution
        t_fix<-system.time(
                pred_buff_glb_fx<-spt_glm_bts_val(mod_fmla=TEMP_2[xx][[1]], Y_col='.mpl.Y', B=0, dataset=df) # B=0 means that there is no bootstrap done :i.e. each formula in the chunck will be fitted only once.
                )         
        t_fix<-as.data.frame(rbind(t_fix))
        
        # run Random models and time the execution
        t_ran<-system.time(
            pred_buff_glb_rn<-spt_glmmPQL_bts_val(mod_fmla=TEMP_2[xx][[1]], random_fmla='~1|ID',Y_col='.mpl.Y', B=0, dataset=df,
                            column_group='ID', RAN.pred=FALSE) 
                )
        t_ran<-as.data.frame(rbind(t_ran))


        pred_buff_glb_fx$mod_type<-'fixed'
        pred_buff_glb_fx$chunk<-xx
        t_fix$chunk<-xx
        t_fix$mod_type<-'fixed'
        
        pred_buff_glb_rn$mod_type<-'random'
        pred_buff_glb_rn$chunk<-xx
        t_ran$chunk<-xx
        t_ran$mod_type<-'random'
        
        # prepare the dataframe with the output for model parameter and performance
        out<-rbind(pred_buff_glb_fx,pred_buff_glb_rn)
        
        # prepare the dataframe with the output for the timing of the custumized model fitting function
        times<-rbind(t_fix,t_ran)
        
        # clean memory 
        rm(pred_buff_glb_fx,pred_buff_glb_rn,t_ran,t_fix)
        gc()
        
        # out
        list(out,times)

        }
)
res
```

##### Parallel version:

For this test I only used 5 cores on 1 node of the Graham cluster (i.e. one physical machine). FYI: the problem persisted also when using more cores and more nodes.

```
# # Create a cluster of child processes 
# --------------------------------------
cl <- makeCluster( 5 )
# set random generator
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, 918734)  # needed because in the customized model fittig functions there is the boostrap procedure (although not run in this example since B=0)


# Load the necessary R package(s) and Distribute the necessary R objects 
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    library(FFspatial)
    })

clusterExport( cl, c('df', 'TEMP_2') )

res<-parLapply(cl,10:15 , function(xx)  {  #### from here to the closing parLapply parenthesis ')' the code is the same of the serial version  
            
        # Run FIXED models
        t_fix<-system.time(
                pred_buff_glb_fx<-spt_glm_bts_val(mod_fmla=TEMP_2[xx][[1]], Y_col='.mpl.Y', B=0, dataset=df) 
                )         
        t_fix<-as.data.frame(rbind(t_fix))
        
        # run Random models with rmse based on fixed predictions
        t_ran<-system.time(
            pred_buff_glb_rn<-spt_glmmPQL_bts_val(mod_fmla=TEMP_2[xx][[1]], random_fmla='~1|ID',Y_col='.mpl.Y', B=0, dataset=df,
                            column_group='ID', RAN.pred=FALSE) 
                )
        t_ran<-as.data.frame(rbind(t_ran))


        pred_buff_glb_fx$mod_type<-'fixed'
        pred_buff_glb_fx$chunk<-xx
        t_fix$chunk<-xx
        t_fix$mod_type<-'fixed'
        
        pred_buff_glb_rn$mod_type<-'random'
        pred_buff_glb_rn$chunk<-xx
        t_ran$chunk<-xx
        t_ran$mod_type<-'random'
        out<-rbind(pred_buff_glb_fx,pred_buff_glb_rn)
        
        times<-rbind(t_fix,t_ran)
        # clean memory 
        rm(pred_buff_glb_fx,pred_buff_glb_rn,t_ran,t_fix)
        gc()
        
        # out
        list(out,times)

        }
)
res
#########

# End cluster
# ---------------

stopCluster(cl)
```

#### Quick facts to recap

Now, if you did not read the comments in my script you need to notice that:

1. the code for the function(xx) is the same for both the serial (lapply) and parallel (parLapply) versions.
2. within the function(xx) the fitting of models is done by my costumized functions `spt_glm_bts_val` and `spt_glmmPQL_bts_val` (which are set to fit only one model for each formula in the chunk meaninng no bootstrapping, B=0 for the sake of this test).
3. the timing is done at the level of `spt_glm_bts_val` and `spt_glmmPQL_bts_val`: thus inside the chunk the from my understanding is sent to different cores when parallelizing and that should run serially on multiple cores

#### Timing results

Here is a summary of the timing recorded from this code run on the HPC cluster:

in both cases:
minimum, maximun and median time (in sec) taken to run 2 models (i.e. one per formula in the chuck in TEMP_2)
'mod_type' indicate if the model was a fixed one (i.e. glm) or a mixed one (i.e. a glmmPQL which needs more time since is fitted through iterations)

##### timing for serial version

```
  mod_type   min    max median
1 fixed    0.319  0.616  0.394
2 random   9.24  12.5   11.8
```

##### timing for parallel version

```
  mod_type   min   max median
1 fixed     14.0  40.2   24.0
2 random   110.  979.   899.
```

As you can see from these results the parellel version is taking way more time then the serial one. this is what I do not understand.

##### DISCLAIMER:

the parallel code reported here uses the parLapply from the 'parallel' package. I did try to use also 'parallel::parLapplyLB' and 'foreach' but I got similar results.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Try removing the calls to `rm` and in particular `gc`. You should never trigger garbage collection manually.

Comment: Have you checked RAM usage? Are you sure the OS doesn't start swapping?

Comment: @Roland, thanks for the advice on rm and gc. I will try to remove them, however those calls are not timed and should not impact on the runtime difference of the model fitting function.... am I wrong?

Comment: @Roland I am not sure how to check the RAM usage on the Cluster and also I have no idea of what an OS swapping is. Can you tell me more?

Comment: When RAM is exhausted, *nix systems can use disk memory (if they are set up to do so). This is called ["swapping"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging#Unix_and_Unix-like_systems). Isn't there something like [`top`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)) on your cluster?

Comment: A main difference between your serial and parallel approach is memory usage. E.g., the parallel approach duplicates `df` for each CPU. I'm not sure that is the issue but it has been the issue for me a few times. R usually needs a lot of memory and that is an important consideration for parallel processing.

Comment: My experience with HPC is very limited and so my comment may not be relevant, because I don't know what SLURM is or does. But generally, one of the operators of the HPC I used said that parallel (I don't know if that refers to the `parallel` package or parallel computing in general) doesn't always distribute the job like one expects. Something to do with distributed versus shared memory parallelization. I think it's shared memory that you want. This allows the cores to communicate during the process. This could be just one contributing factor to the points raised by Roland.

Comment: MPI is an HPC tool that ensures shared memory and there is an R package to help implement it. http://fisher.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/yu/Rmpi/ You will probably also need to call an MPI software on your HPC. On mine it's called OpenMPI. So on the HPC I use, I set my environment, then something like `./usr/apps/OpenMPI`, then `R CMD <script with Rmpi call included>`. Obviously, this is just an example and may not be applicable to your set up.